# How does water slows down neutrons in moderation?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutrons

I have read that nuclear reactors mostly use water (sometimes solid graphite too) for slowing down very fast neutrons. How exactly water helps in slowing neutrons and why only water ( and other substances like solid graphite)?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/moder.html

Answer (score 2):

The key points are elastic collisions.  From elementary physics of collisions between two billard balls, it is only possible for the projectile to be stopped if the target (initially at rest) has the same mass as the bullet.  Thus, roughly speaking, particles or atoms of roughly the same mass as the neutron will work best.

In water, it is the hydrogen that "does the slowing".  There are chemical elements lighter than graphite but the choice there is driven by the availability of the stuff in sufficiently large and purified quantities.

There are also questions of absorption cross sections, which depend on the energy of the bullet and on the details of the actual target nucleus.  Whereas hydrogen in water ought to work best, it can absorb neutrons (rather than just slow them) much better than heavy water, in which hydrogen nuclei are replaced by deuterium, a less neutron-absorbing nucleus.

---

As a historical note: the first sustained nuclear chain reaction was achieved by Fermi at the University of Chicago, while he was working for the Manhattan project in December 1942.  The reactor was moderated by graphite.  The Germans project was lead by Heisenberg and used heavy water as a moderator, leading to a series of heroic raids by Norwegians on the only plant that could produce heavy water on the scale needed for German nuclear research.

Comment: How do they 'absorb' neutrons?

Comment: My friend: that's another question altogether.  A very simplified version would be: the neutron is described by a (localized) wave packet which has some probability of penetrating the nucleus for a sufficiently long time so as to allow the nuclear force to act and trap the neutron.  Because of the wave-like nature of the particle, there are resonance conditions on capture which are quite dependent on the energy.  An analogy would be with thin films, which can become reflectionless for light having the right wavelength.